# render function not recognised in R Studio

Tags: r, r-markdown

Bit of a newbie for `R`, `R Studio` and `Markdown` but I am trying to use the `render()` function on my `Rmd` file and I get the following error:

```
Error: could not find function "render"
```

If I try to use the following I get this error:

```
markdown::render("MarkdownExample.Rmd")
Error: 'render' is not an exported object from 'namespace:markdown'
```

Still yesterday I could use the render fonction without any problem. Would anyone know what to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rmarkdown::render`?

Comment: @Consistency can't believe I was that silly. Thanks. Please post as an answer, I will accept right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `rmarkdown::render`?